# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date

Tags: java

i am trying to insert Date into database column type Date 
getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date`

code:

```
Date dateFormatter = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(requiredByDate.toString());
java.sql.Date requiredByDate1 = new java.sql.Date(dateFormatter.getTime());
```

set to prepared statement:

```
pstmt.setDate(1, requiredByDate1);
```

got a error

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date
```

pls suggest how to resolve this.

Thanks

Comment: post your code and the exact stack trace

Comment: you shouldn't even need to `cast` it in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Your code and the error message does not match. You have to be using some other version of the code.

You have:

```
java.sql.Date requiredByDate1 = ...
pstmt.setDate(1, requiredByDate1);
```

but that code cannot result in

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date
```

as it's not java.util.Date.

Answer (score 0):

Your Code Here is :

```
Date dateFormatter = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").
                                               parse(requiredByDate.toString());
```

Now Your **Date** may be either :

**1) java.util.Date**  , OR

**2) java.sql.Date** ,  which ultimately is a Sub-class of **java.util.Date.**

However,

```
SimpleDateFormat class belongs to java.text package. And you are trying to cast 
an object of java.text.SimpleDateFormat to java.util.Date( OR java.sql.Date)
which is why you are getting java.lang.ClassCastException
```